# wordpress point existing subdirectory to root url

Tags: wordpress

I have this url > http://example.com and I installed wordpress in subfolder named wordpress (which it goes to http://example.com/wordpress) and I done all my posts, pages, woocommerce etc. in there.

Now I wanna point http://example.com to that subfolder and I refer to this guide http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change

My question here is... do I need to move my wp-content/upload folder to root after I do search replace URL in my database? Cause when I start doing search replace process, the image path will be replaced as well. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to upload your files to the http://example.com/wordpress, then you should replace urls in your sql file.. replace "example.com/" with example.com/wordpress .. I think this must work. if not just ping here